# Restoring a message to the queue

Tags: rabbitmq

After using Dequeue() to my queue, I want to restore the retrieved message to the queue. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't auto acknowledging messages then it will get re-queued in the absence of an explicit acknowledgement.
If you are auto acknowledging then you should just manually enqueue it.

So, if you are doing something like:

```
BasicDeliverEventArgs e = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
```

then you can do something like:

```
consumer.Queue.Enqueue(e);
```

Is that the sort of thing you were after?

Comment: I suspect he doesn't want to Ack, but instead Reject the message with requeue=true. This is possible if you set auto-ack to false when setting up the consumer.